# Clang5.0: previous declaration in "__hash_table"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

We switched to C ++ 17 and so Clang ++ 5.0 to get its features. But we encounter problems with `/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map` which calls `/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table` file. It seems that Clang raise previous declaration in this file.

For your information, with GCC-5.4 this compiles very well. Here is the output error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:369:
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1132:43: error: conflicting types for '__hash_table<_Tp, _Hash,
      _Equal, _Alloc>'
__hash_table<_Tp, _Hash, _Equal, _Alloc>::__hash_table()
                                          ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:839:5: note: previous declaration is here
    __hash_table()
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1200:43: error: conflicting types for '__hash_table<_Tp, _Hash,
      _Equal, _Alloc>'
__hash_table<_Tp, _Hash, _Equal, _Alloc>::__hash_table(__hash_table&& __u)
                                          ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:853:5: note: previous declaration is here
    __hash_table(__hash_table&& __u)
    ^
```

In the file, we simply do `#include <unordered_map>`.

I have tried both libstdc ++ and libc ++, but both give me the same error while with GCC no.

Has anyone ever had this problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: So the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is simply the single `#include` and nothing more?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately, currently I can't reproduced error with just include `unordered_map`. I'm trying to find an minimal example to reproduce error.

Comment: I got the same compile errors - see [here](https://travis-ci.org/onqtam/game/jobs/308129361)

Comment: @onqtam I've edit my question. change include order solved it for me.

Comment: Algorys, you should make an *answer* with the solution rather than adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error with a minimal example but I did not succeed.

I still solved the error. I think it's a problem related to the import order in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(BEFORE "/usr/include/c++/5")
include_directories(AFTER "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/")
```

Then no more compilation errors.